# Analysis of residuals on test set: My residuals have a linear relation with a non-zero mean

Tags: regression, feature-selection, residuals

i have been trying some modelisation with training sets (132 individuals) and testing sets (32 individuals). My models have 3 variables which have been selected through PCA (won't extend on the method as it was shown in Cross-validation that it outperformed lasso and RF).

**I wanted to give a look on the residuals for the Test Set but i was heavily disapointed.
My residuals would follow an equation with a non-zero coefficient for the slope.**

Here some pictures of the residuals. **Bawac is the name of the variable. Even Full and Odd are the names of the testing and training datasets, they are all slightly different.** [image]

And just the regression graph against true values [image]

Now my thoughts are that it is because my models lack good variables.

**So i also tried LASSO with CV.GLMNET. It gave me bigger models (around 5 variables). And the result was basically the same, or even worse.**

My final thought is that my dataset lacks good variables (around 60)

**Do you have any idea for :

- If this is common result for a testing set
- The root cause of my issue**

Comment: Do you have outliers in your training data?

Comment: i have taken the outliers out in the original whole dataset based on the the response variable. I know its a problem to do so, i just wanted to try it to see if they were "forcing" the regression equation out of the real corpus of points. The graphs i'm showing are from models calibrated on the data without outliers (5th and 95th percentiles of the response variable)

Comment: Can you nonetheless post another image in your question of the training data and the relationship with the variables?